# Django - how to get email links to work on mobile?

Tags: python, django, html-email

My Django site sends out an email confirmation link, and everything seems to work fine on desktop. On mobile devices, however, the link text is highlighted blue and underlined (i.e. it looks like a link) but nothing happens when the user clicks it. It should open a browser tab and say, "you have confirmed your email, etc"

Thanks for any tips!

**views.py:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #send signup form
        email_address = request.POST['email']
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email_address)
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': "Email already in use."})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                #auth.login(request, user)
                #send email confirmation link then redirect:
                #user = User.objects.get(email=email_address)
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                mail_subject = 'Welcome to My Site'
                plain_msg = 'Thank you for signing up to My Site! Click this link to activate your account:\n\n'+current_site.domain+'/accounts/activated/'+urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()+'/'+account_activation_token.make_token(user)+'/'
                msg = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>title</title></head><body>Confirm your email address to continue:<br/><a href="'+current_site.domain+'/accounts/activated/'+urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()+'/'+account_activation_token.make_token(user)+'/">Confirm my email address</a></body></html>'
                print(msg)
                send_mail(mail_subject, plain_msg, 'my_email@gmail.com', [email_address], html_message=msg)
                return render(request, 'accounts/activation-link-sent.html', {'email': email_address})
    #truncated for Stack Overflow post
```

Comment: Nothing happens at all when you click the link? Is this in an email app?

Comment: Try adding `target="_blank"` to the link

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, nothing happens. It's weird. The two users who showed me this were both using an email app, yes.

Comment: Is it every user that uses an app and is it the same app? It may be that the app is blocking the link. Does the link include the protocol? (http/https)

Comment: The plain and the html email have different links... can you add a piece of text to one or the other so that you know which is being rendered for the user?

Comment: As you can see it was http no https, even though my site is https.

Comment: I would delete the comment with the link in as it contains your domain and a validation token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) to create fully qualified links that include the current domain and protocol, then use this link in your email

```
link = request.build_absolute_uri('/accounts/activated/'+urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()+'/'+account_activation_token.make_token(user)+'/')
```

Do you have a url pattern that matches this URL? You should consider using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) for building URLs

```
path = reverse('activate', kwargs={
    'pk': user.pk,
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)
})
link = request.build_absolute_uri(path)
```

Comment: Thanks Iain - I do have a URL pattern in place so I've left that alone for now. I used `request.build_absolute_uri` and deleted a user account and had them sign up again, and the email confirmation link worked perfectly from their email app.